# Return Worksheet names for workbooks in a directory along with column names and null value count for each column

Tags: python

I am absolutely new to python and needed some help- 
I want to loop through all files in a specified directory to-
Return names of all excel workbooks within it, return worksheet names and the column headers for it.

So the o/p could be like-
Workbook name - worksheet Name - column names - null value count

Comment: It will be good if you can provide a sample code you tried and some sample data.

Comment: Well, I don't have any code as such, but can give more details-
1. I want to list all files (Excel Workbooks) present in a folder
2. For Every File, I want to list the worksheets contained within it
3. For every Worksheet, I want to list the Column names
4. For every Column, I want to list the null value count

So, the o/p can be something like-
File: 'Orders.xlsx'
Sheets: 'North'
and then for each column- Total count and Null Value count